# How to Improve the Speed of Scanning and focus of Qr Code?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I am using Zing Library for scan Qr code.

```
  case ZXING_LINK:
    if (scanFromWebPageManager == null || !scanFromWebPageManager.isScanFromWebPage()) {
      handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
    } else {
      handleDecodeExternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);
    }
```

I want to Improve the Speed of scanning and focus. it  takes time to focus and scan.

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/vision/, i hope this will help

Comment: Did you add the permission for using the autofocus in the manifest.xml ?